# Elasticsearch Nested Filter Sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to sort my data by specific array field.

I got products, and categories. One product can have many categories. And product-category matching has its own priority to sort my products.

```
[{

        "title":"Product 1",
        "categories": [{
                "title": "Category 1",
                "pivot": {
                 "priority": 10
                }
            }, {
                "title": "Category 2",
                "pivot": {
                 "priority": 3
                }
            },{
                "title": "Category 3",
                "pivot": {
                 "priority": 8
                }
            },{
                "title": "Category 4",
                "pivot": {
                 "priority": 2
                }
            }
        ]
    },{
        "title":"Product 2",
        "categories": [{
                "title": "Category 1",
                "pivot": {
                 "priority": 3
                }
            }, {
                "title": "Category 2",
                "pivot": {
                 "priority": 8
                }
            },{
                "title": "Category 3",
                "pivot": {
                 "priority": 2
                }
            },{
                "title": "Category 4",
                "pivot": {
                 "priority": 6
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to list my products by 'Category 1' and sort them with its priority.
I made a query like below. (I shared only inside sorting)

```
{
  "categories.pivot.priority": {
    "order": "asc",
    "nested_path": "categories",
    "nested_filter": {
      "term": {
        "categories.title.keyword": "Category 1"
      } 
  }
}
```

But when I make It,
It returns

```
[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"[nested] nested object under path [categories] is not of nested
```

Couldn understand whats wrong with it.